# How do I map the std::_Ios_Openmode passed to basic_fstream to an actual value?

Tags: disassembly, c++, arm

I am working on some ARM disassembly. A file is being operated on:

```
0000e550  sub  r3, r11, #0x2d0
0000e554  mov  r0, r3        ; /tmp/MAC
0000e558  ldr  r1, = 0x9a60c ; 0xec04 (sub_e3a8 + 0x85c)
0000e55c  mov  r2, #0x8      ; std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_fstream(char const*,std::_Ios_Openmode)
0000e560  bl   _ZNSt13basic_fstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1EPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode@PLT ; std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)
```

`r0` is "`this`", `r1` is the path (`/tmp/MAC`) and `r2` is the mode. As can be seen, the mode is `0x8`.

The mode is "implementation defined" according to [several sources](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode). I haven't got specifics of the implementation unfortunately.

What is the typical implementation of this on ARM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to find out which compiler/library is being used, then check the specs of that compiler.

Assuming it's `gcc` with `libstdc++` (this is quite probable if you're on android; less probable on Windows RT), googling for "gcc libstd ios_base openmode" yields https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00504.html, which tells it's defined in ios_base.h. Navigating there, you can find

```
00112   enum _Ios_Openmode 
00113     { 
00114       _S_app        = 1L << 0,
00115       _S_ate        = 1L << 1,
00116       _S_bin        = 1L << 2,
00117       _S_in         = 1L << 3,
00118       _S_out        = 1L << 4,
00119       _S_trunc      = 1L << 5,
00120       _S_ios_openmode_end = 1L << 16 
00121     };
```

and

```
static const openmode in =      _S_in;
```

so the open mode is probably `in`.

But, unless you find out which compiler was used, this a guess, and we can only help you guessing.